# Getting error when we are trying to download more than 2500 rows from obiee12c analytics

Tags: oracle, obiee

We are getting the following error message when we are trying to download data more than 2500 rows from the obiee12c analytics.

```
There was an error processing your download.
Please check with your administrator
```

OBIEE version: 12.2.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, InputStreamLimitInKB setting in OBIEE will need to be increased.

To increase the InputStreamLimitInKB limit:

Browse to $OBIEE_Domain/config/fmwconfig/biconfig/OBIJH
Open the config.xml
Find the following lines:

```
<XMLP>
   <InputStreamLimitInKB>8192</InputStreamLimitInKB>
   <ReadRequestBeforeProcessing>true</ReadRequestBeforeProcessing>
</XMLP>
```

Change the InputStreamLimitInKB value from 8192 to 1024000.

Save and close the file.
Then restart the OBIEE12c services.

Comment: Thanks for you support

Answer (score 0):

The download of rows is controlled by several different settings in addition to the one mentioned above in the other response. Way too many to list in the post, but they are shown and explained in detail here:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIESG/answersconfigset.htm#BIESG3278

Those settings go hand in hand with increasing the InputStreamLimitInKB.